# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in NSDate formatting extention

Tags: ios, swift2, nsdate, exc-bad-access, foundation

I'm writing an extension for NSDate which provides some failable initializers. The end goal here is to get a date time string from an API and parse it into an NSDate, e.g.

```
let createdAt = NSDate(apiDateTimeString: "2016-03-29T18:33:49+06:00")
let createdAt = NSDate(apiDateTimeString: "2016-03-29T18:33:49.730+06:00")
```

The date time string can take one of 2 formats:

- `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ`
- `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ`

Here is what the extension looks like:

```
import Foundation

public extension NSDate {

    // MARK: Custom Initializers

    public convenience init(date: NSDate) {
        self.init(timeInterval: 0.0, sinceDate: date)
    }

    public convenience init?(dateString: String, formatString: String) {
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = formatString
        formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        if let date = formatter.dateFromString(dateString) {
            self.init(date: date)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    public convenience init?(apiDateTimeString: String?) {
        guard let dateString = apiDateTimeString else {
            return nil
        }
        if NSDate(dateString: dateString, formatString: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ") != nil {
            self.init(dateString: dateString, formatString: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ")
        } else {
            self.init(dateString: dateString, formatString: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ")
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to use this, it get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` at `if NSDate(dateString: dateString, formatString: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ") != nil`

Any help figuring out why this isn't working is appreciated.

EDIT: I forgot to add: this worked with Swift 2.1, and quit working with Swift 2.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an issue in Swift 2.2. For more information, see [SR-704: EXC_BAD_ACCESS on returning nil from a failable initializer of NSObject subclass](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-704). Looks like it was fixed in the mainline branch, but didn’t make it into the final Swift 2.2 release. Expect it to be fixed in the next point update.

As a temporary workaround, make sure to to always initialize the object before returning `nil` from a failable initializer (or throwing from a throwing initializer). That is, insert `self.init()` before every `return nil` statement.

*Edit: This issue has been fixed in Swift 2.2.1/Xcode 7.3.1. It should no longer be necessary to initialize the instance before returning `nil`.*

Comment: That did it. Thank you very much :)